# Restart running python Scrip when get error in android termux

Tags: python, android, termux

I have mylooop.pyc python script and running all day in termux on androidOS
but some times get error and crashed or when  internet connection its get error.

1. question : I want to when error or crash or connect lost its restart itself  automatically
2. can we do it with last script caches?

I'm try a lots solution but still same.
thank u for your answers from now.

````
from time import sleep
import sys
import os
restart_timer = 2
def start_script():
        try:
                
                os.system('python mylooop.pyc')
        except :
                handle_crash()
def handle_crash():
        sleep(restart_timer)  # Restarts the script after 2 seconds
        start_script()

start_script()```
````

Comment: you can't `try...except` around `os.system`, you need to handle code **in** the python code that's running. If you show your code for that, we might be able to help

Comment: I need to do it with new python script or any termux tricks.the main script encrypted.